# Non-intrusively adding code to lambda asset bundle during CDK Synth with IAspect or other methods

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I'm working on a way to add code to an AWS Lambda Asset during the CDK Synth process.

**What I've Tried**

I have an IAspect which visits each node on a construct and looks for lambdas. I am able to find the reference to the asset which will be deployed to AWS, however, adding code to the the Asset folder in the cdk.out directory does not deploy the added code to the Lambda. This is because during the synthesis process, the lambda's code directory is ran through a hash to check for changes in the bundle that will be sent up, since the code is added post-hash, the bundle sees no changes as being made and doesn't modify the code that will be deployed to the lambda. I haven't found a non-intrusive way to add code to a lambda's bundle without actually modifying the source code. Is anyone familiar with any other methods I may be able to employ to accomplish this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Why do you need to add code after synth? There might be other ways.

Comment: The goal is to not modify the source code and have an automated way to add code to lambdas that meet certain criteria. This would be helpful for projects that have large amounts of lambdas.

Comment: You are explaining what Aspects do, which I am aware of. What I am trying to understand is what you are trying to achieve in your project.